# Login with Single Table Inheritance

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity `Account` and two tables inherited with Single Table Inheritance from it: `Client` and `Administrator`.

I have a login form that uses the `Account` table. Once the user is logged in, I get the information like this:

```
    $account = $this->em->getRepository ( 'Entities\Account' )
   ->findOneByEmail ( $email ) );
```

I get the account with no problem, but the issue is: how do I find out if the user is a Client or an Administrator? I know I can do `get_class` and see which class it's using, but I don't think that's the correct way. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just add a column to table `Account` which would hold the rank?

Comment: I feel it would be redundant. To have the entity Client, and have a column that says that the rank is "client", is that what you mean/

Comment: I mean to have a column called rank ( doesn't really matter how it's called ) which will hold numbers, where numbers will have meanings. Say 0 will be client, 1 will be admin and so on, which also opens you for easy adding of ranks in future

Comment: That's what I mean. Wouldnt that be redundant?

Comment: I can't seem to follow your logic, how do you find a rank identifier redundant?

Comment: Because I already have the Entities "Client" and "Administrator". So besides being in the Client entity, they would also have a column that says they are a client. I feel that's like having two discr columns. Am I wrong?

Comment: @raygo can you show tables structure? I mean `Account`, `Administrator` and `Client`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not want to use get_class 
you would do something like this

```
class Client extends Account
{
    protected $discr  = 'client';
    ...
}

class Administrator extends Account
{
    protected $discr  = 'administrator';
    ...
}
```

a field in the object (not in the database)

and create getType() method in Acount class

Comment: I used this solution, but I thought Doctrine would have something else